# Using images for points in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a frivolous question. Is there any way to use an image in lieu of points in gnuplot? For example, if I was plotting data about pasta consumption or something, I would have pictures of pasta (instead of usual gnuplot points).

Comment: See another more precise Q&A on this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36886170/gnuplot-plot-image-at-point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Revisited 10 years later**

Gnuplot 5.4 supports `pixmap` objects that can be placed within the coordinate space of a plot.  See answer to [gnuplot: Use an image instead of a point type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77224162/gnuplot-use-an-image-instead-of-a-point-type/77224407#77224407)

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to find a dingbats type of font with a suitable glyph. Then you can use "plot with labels" using that glyph as the label string.  See for example the 5th plot in the demo
   http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/stringvar.html

Answer (score 1):

I haven't played around with this feature at all myself, however, there is:

http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/barchart_art.html

Which shows the use of png files on a bar chart (Note, that this feature was added in Gnuplot 4.5 -- I think).  With a little creativity, it seems like you could use that feature to do what you're asking -- although it would require a whole bunch of plot commands so it might be useful to write a script to generate the gnuplot script (or use iteration depending on your dataset) -- Obviously your image files would have to be in a format that your version of gnuplot understands as well ...

Answer (score 0):

A possible strategy may be the `plot with rgbimage` option in gnuplot.

See the second example over here: http://www.gnuplot.info/demo_4.2/image.html

If you relate the `center` option with your data points, this may be possible.