# gnuplot: Use an image instead of a point type

Tags: image, gnuplot

I have read this article ([Gnuplot - plot image at point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36886170/gnuplot-plot-image-at-point)) showing how to use an image instead of a Point Type on a chart by utilizing a vector containing the names of the images together with in array of values and iteration with the For command.

Is there a "simpler" way to get this effect or is the method shown in the article above the only way to accomplish this goal with gnuplot?

One of my many failed attempts trying to bend gnuplot to my will to use an image instead of a point type:

```
$DATA<<EOD
1,"c:\temp\image1.png",0.00,0.00
2,"c:\temp\image1.png",424.75,549.75
3,"c:\temp\image1.png",849.50,1099.50
4,"c:\temp\image2.png",1274.25,1649.25
5,"c:\temp\image2.png",1698.00,2198.00
EOD
set terminal windows enhanced size 1700,2200
set datafile separator comma
set style data point
unset xtics
unset ytics
set border 0
set key off
set xrange [0:1699]
set yrange [0:2199]
plot $DATA with image '$2' binary filetype=png center=($3,$4) rgbimage
```

Thank you
Roberto

Comment: that's funny... the last days I've been experimenting with this type of plotting (actually, moon phases), without knowing about the linked post. Do you explictly want a pixel image or is maybe just a simple shape (e.g. half circle, heptagon, drop, eye, etc...) enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current gnuplot (version 5.4) also supports `pixmap` objects.  These are not exactly point types, but they can be positioned using graph coordinates so that they act as points within a graph.  This works for both 2D and 3D graphs.

Here is an example based on the one you show. Note that the plot is created `with points`, but the pre-defined pixmaps cover those points.

```
PIC = "icon64x64.png"

$DATA<<EOD
1 0.00 0.00
2 424.75 549.75
3 849.50 1099.50
4 1274.25 1649.25
5 1698.00 2198.00
EOD

set for [i=1:5] pixmap i PIC center at word($DATA[i], 2), word($DATA[i], 3)

set xrange [0:2000]
set yrange [0:2400]

plot $DATA using 2:3 with points notitle
```

[image]

Other possible uses of `pixmap` are shown in the online [pixmap demo](https://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.4/pixmap.html) (best to run this one locally so you can see that the pixmap icon moves with graph in 3D as you rotate interactively.

**Edit**:

The `word` function as shown works only for strings where the individual fields are separated by whitespace. If for some reason it is essential to deal with commas or other field separators, you can look forward to a more general solution in gnuplot 6 (available as a release candidate; full release expected by the end of 2023).
In gnuplot 6 you could use the `split` function instead of `word`. The revised code to handle comma-separated fields would look like this:

```
# gnuplot version 6
do for [j=1:5] {
    A = split( $DATA[j], "," )
    set pixmap j PIC center at A[2], A[3]
}
```

Comment: Ethan, Thank you.

Issuing a set pixmap commands for each image works but your approach to use the iteration with the "for" command will minimize the length of instructions. 

I modified your script to have the coordinates separated by commas and I only get one image on the plot or all images on the same position... why is that?

PIC = "icon64x64.png"
$DATA<<EOD
1,0,0
2,1,1
3,10,10
4,20,20
5,30,30
EOD
set datafile separator comma
set for [i=1:5] pixmap i PIC center at word($DATA[i], 2), word($DATA[i], 3)
plot $DATA using ($2):($3) with points notitle

Comment: The "word" function assumes that words are separated by white space. It should still work so long as each comma has a space after it.

Comment: Amazing... thank you again.

Comment: Ethan, the issue with the space separator is that the location of the image file(s) is out of my control, so if the user wants to use an image file located in "c:\\Temp\\New Folder\\myimage.png" gnuplot is not going to like that. 

Thank you for the ver 6 approach.

Roberto

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to plot certain shapes (not PNG images) at certain locations, the following might be an option.
You define your shapes as parametric curves and plot them `with lines` or `with filledcurves`.
You could also use datablocks for defining shapes, e.g. clouds, trees, or other symbols. You have to `set size ratio -1` or otherwise scale your shapes with appropriate x- and y-factors.

**Script:** (works with gnuplot>=5.2.0, Aug. 2017)

```
### plot various shapes at x,y positions
reset session
set angles degrees
set size ratio -1

$StarPos <<EOD
0    7   1.2
1    3   1.0
2   10   0.7
3    5   0.5
5    8   1.5
EOD

$SunPos <<EOD
10    4    1.0
14    5    2.0
20    6    3.0
EOD

# x,y, phase, size
# phases: 0=new moon, 0.5=full moon, 1=new moon
$MoonPos <<EOD
 0   0   0.00   1.0
 3   0   0.125  1.0
 6   0   0.25   1.0
 9   0   0.375  1.0
12   0   0.50   1.0
15   0   0.625  1.0
18   0   0.75   1.0
21   0   0.875  1.0
24   0   1.00   1.0
EOD

array Star[n_star=10]  # twice the number of spikes
StarX(n) = (s=$StarPos[i], A=word(s,3), a=$0*360./n_star+90, A*(cos(a)*(int($0)%2 ? 0.4 : 1)) + word(s,1))
StarY(n) = A*(sin(a)*(int($0)%2 ? 0.4 : 1)) + word(s,2)

array Sun [n_sun=42]   # three times the number of rays
SunX(n) = (s=$SunPos[i], A=word(s,3), a=$0*360./n_sun+90, A*(cos(a)*(int($0)%3 ? 0.5 : 1)) + word(s,1))
SunY(n) = A*(sin(a)*(int($0)%3 ? 0.5 : 1)) + word(s,2)

array Moon[n_moon=40]   # high enough even number to get a "round" shape
r(x)     =  2*(x - abs(x)) + 1
MoonX(n) = (a=360./n_moon*$0+90, s=$MoonPos[i/2+1], p=word(s,3), A=word(s,4), \
           A*cos(a)*(i%2 ? a<=270 ? r(p-0.5) : r(0.5-p) : \
           (a<=270 ^ p<=0.5) ? -r(p-0.5) : r(0.5-p)) + word(s,1))
MoonY(n) = A*sin(a) + word(s,2)

set key noautotitle
set style fill noborder

plot for [i=1:|$StarPos|]     Star u (StarX(0)):(StarY(0)) w filledcurves fc "yellow", \
     for [i=1:|$SunPos|]       Sun u (SunX(0)) :(SunY(0))  w filledcurves lc "yellow", \
     for [i=0:|$MoonPos|*2-1] Moon u (MoonX(0)):(MoonY(0)):(i%2?0xffff00:0x000077) w filledcurves lc rgb var
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you theozh,

Your answer is way more complex than the issue I am trying to address, but I appreciate your time looking at my question.

Roberto